# Which field is this Django field and how to use it?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This can be found in Django Admin, under Groups table.

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zzL9.jpg

As I see, it is a `<select>` html tag with the `multiple` option (`<select multiple>`).
How can we achieve it in custom tables, and how can we handle them?

I looked up the django documentation, but it's not that documented (if I found the right one).

Comment: This is a `ManyToMany`-Field which is listed in the `ModelAdmin`'s  [`filter_horizontal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal).

Comment: See the [source code of the `GroupAdmin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with a **`FilteredSelectMultiple`** widget. You can import this widget from the admin widgets. This will also require CSS and JavaScript. In your form you thus can work with:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

class SomeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        widgets = {
            'some_field': FilteredSelectMultiple('SomeField', False)
        }
    
    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('/static/admin/css/widgets.css',),
        }
        js = ('/admin/jsi18n',)
```

You then render the form with:

```
<form method="post" action="…">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.media }}
    {{ form }}
</form>
```